# Prove isomorphism in infinite-dim condition

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, general-topology

It disturbs me a lot how to do with "Infinite" space in solving problems like the following one.

Let *S$_{1}$, S$_{2}$* and *V$_{1}$, V$_{2}$* be subspaces of *V*. Suppose that *V=V$_{1}$$\oplus$V$_{2}$* and *S=S$_{1}$$\oplus$S$_{2}$*.

$\oplus$ means direct sum here. And *S$_{1}$$\subset$V$_{1}$ ,S$_{2}$$\subset$V$_{2}$*.

Prove that *V/S=(V$_{1}$$\oplus$V$_{2}$)/(S$_{1}$$\oplus$S$_{2}$) is isomorphic to (V$_{1}$/S$_{1}$)$\times$(V$_{2}$*/S$_{2}$).

Comment: Are $S_1\subset V_1$ and  $S_2\subset V_2$?

Comment: What does $\oplus$ mean?

Comment: @WilliamElliot: it denotes the direct sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define:

$$\phi:V\to V_1/S_1\times V_2/S_2\;,\;\;\phi v:=\left(v_1+S_1,\,v_2+S_2\right)$$

where we've written $\;v=v_1+v_2\;,\;\;v_i\in V_i\;$, and this expression is **unique** (why?) .

Show $\;\phi\;$ is a linear map and also that $\;\ker V=S=S_1\oplus S_2\;$